# setting bold font to each <li> when hover it

Tags: jquery, html, css

I like to construct my program in way that when I `mouseover` to certain `<li>` its font-weight changes to Bold , other `<li>'s` still had normal font-weight and when I `mouseout` from that special `<li>` its font returns to Normal ! it have to work for all `<li>` tags...

In my code if I `a:hover` its and childes font-weight's will set to bold(its not what I want) !

Its good to me if I a:hover or `a1:hover` just a or a1 `font-weight` changes to bold .

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/w7hgqket/11/) is the Fiddle.

```
<ul>
    <li>a
        <ul>
            <li>a1</li>
            <li>a2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>b
        <ul>
            <li>b1</li>
            <li>b2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>

**CSS**

li{
        list-style-type:none;
}
ul li{
    float:left;
    width:100px;
    height:40px;
    background-color:pink;
    border:solid 1px black;
    list-style-type:none;
    text-align:center;
    margin-left:1px;
}
li ul li{
    margin-left:-41px;
    margin-top:0px;
    position:relative;
    z-index:100;
    clear:both;
}
li ul{
    margin-top:20px;
}
ul li ul {
    display:none;
}
li:hover ul{
    display:block;
}
ul > li:hover{
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

Comment: Refer this - http://www.scientificpsychic.com/etc/css-mouseover.html

Answer (score 5):

Simply use CSS like this:

```
li li:hover {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Erase your last CSS rule, too.

Hope this helps!

Comment: your kidding me ? : )

Comment: Since an `ul` can only contain a `li`, you could reduce to `li li:hover {`

Comment: a and b font-weight is not bold after hovering ... said I like each <li> have to appear bold after hovering !and appear normal after mouseout. it means at a time just one <li> should be Bold after hovering

Answer (score 1):

Erase your last CSS rule and use :

```
ul li ul li:hover {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: it does not work for a and b ! their fonts not changed to bold !

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative answer to the basic CSS, using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) (since the question is tagged as such):

```
$("li").hover(function()
{
    $(this).css("font-weight", 'bold');
});
```

[Working demo using jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/asbjt705/)

**Edit**

If you want it to work for every single sub-li then you must change the code to:

```
$("li li").hover(function()
{
    $(this).css("font-weight", 'bold');
});
```

[Woring demo using jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/asbjt705/3/)

Comment: Not the edit part either? How is it different to what you're looking for? And you're welcome.

Comment: I never like to see 2 or higher bold <Li> in output. it means we have to consider just one bold <Li> at a time and infact that <li> has hovered

Comment: @KeivanSabil... The second demo only bolds one <li> at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Not perfectly sure if the jQuery method works, 100% that the css method should work though.

CSS:

```
li:hover {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$('li:hover').css('font-weight','bold');
```

Comment: No, the JQuery won't work. As it is, will only set as bold the `li` that is hovered at the moment of the method call...

Comment: Yeah i should have used:

$('li').hover(function(){ $(this).css('font-weight','bold'); });

Answer (score 0):

finally I solved my problem myown : |

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/w7hgqket/12/) is the Fiddle.

HTML =

```
<ul>
       <li>
               <div id="div_a">a</div>
                <ul>
                    <li><div class="c1">a1</div></li>
                    <li><div class="c1">a2</div></li>
                </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

CSS =

```
    li{
            list-style-type:none;
    }
    ul li{
        float:left;
        width:100px;
        height:40px;
        background-color:pink;
        border:solid 1px black;
        list-style-type:none;
        text-align:center;
        margin-left:1px;
    }
    li ul li{
        margin-left:-41px;
        margin-top:12px;
        position:relative;
        z-index:100;
        clear:both;
    }
    li ul{
        margin-top:20px;
    }
    #div_a:hover ,  .c1:hover{
        font-weight:bold;
    }
```